# R does not list row numbers in brackets

Tags: r, brackets

I have a problem that is hampering my analyses. For some weird reason, whenever I import a table (csv, text etc) I never get the row numbers to appear in brackets. Instead of this:

```
>ID Year  
[1,]  1 1944  
[2,]  1 1945  
[3,]  1 1946
```

I get this:

> ID Year
>       1  1 1944
>       2  1 1945
>       3  1 1946

The problem is that R ends up using the first column (1,2,3) as ID and ruins the analysis.
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you importing the table? What function are you using? In what format is the data that you're trying to import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *"object printed with row numbers in brackets"* is probably a [`matrix`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html), while reading from csv you get a [`data.frame`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html).

If you call `as.matrix()` on the `data.frame` you get by reading the csv, you will obtain the desired result.

**e.g. :**

A matrix object like this:

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1944,1945,1946),nrow=3,ncol=2)
colnames(m1) <- c('ID','Year')

m1
```

yields:

```
> m1
     ID Year
[1,]  1 1944
[2,]  1 1945
[3,]  1 1946
```

While reading the same data from a csv:

```
m2 <- read.csv(text="ID,Year
1,1944
1,1945
1,1946")

m2
```

you get:

```
> m2
  ID Year
1  1 1944
2  1 1945
3  1 1946
```

Converting m2 to a matrix:

```
m3 <- as.matrix(m2)
m3
```

you get this:

```
> m3
     ID Year
[1,]  1 1944
[2,]  1 1945
[3,]  1 1946
```

Comment: Hi digEmAll, that's really good, thanks a lot. I realised the package I am using needs matrices not dataframes, which is why I need to convert them the way you did. Thank you very much.